# Change psysh dark blue color

Tags: php, bash, shell, colors, color-scheme

I am looking for a way to change the dark blue color that is displayed in output of `psysh` interactive shell prompt for PHP. Is it a bash color issue? If so, what is the variable of `dircolors` that change that dark blue?

If not how can I change the color scheme or only the dark blue text output of `psysh`?

Comment: Edit [ShellOutput.php](https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh/blob/master/src/Psy/Output/ShellOutput.php) (initFormatters)

Comment: That's it. Thanks a lot. Why not an answer?

Comment: No problem. Wasn't sure specifically which style it was :P Wrote it as an answer for other people searching

Comment: You could also change your Shell's blue color to be legible over the background :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit the [ShellOutput.php](https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh/blob/master/src/Psy/Output/ShellOutput.php) file in the `initFormatters()` function